# Iterate over json with angular 7 using services

Tags: node.js, json, angular

I have a node server that returns the following JSON:

```
{
        "ResponseStatus": {
          "ResponseCode": 0,
          "ResponseMessage": "Success."
        },
        "Events": [
          {
            "CodEspec": 65957,
            "NomeEspec": "O PIOR ESPETÁCULO DO MUNDO",
            "DiaHoraEspecs": [
              "2019-05-09T21:30:00",
              "2019-05-10T21:30:00",
              "2019-05-25T21:30:00"
            ]
          },
          {
            "CodEspec": 01234,
            "NomeEspec": "O MELHOR ESPETÁCULO DO MUNDO",
            "DiaHoraEspecs": [
              "2019-05-09T21:30:00",
              "2019-05-10T21:30:00",
              "2019-05-25T21:30:00"
            ]
          },

        ]
      }
```

I created an angular service that executes a GET and returns the JSON.

**tickeline.service.ts**

```
getEventos():Observable<Event[]>{
    //get todos os eventos
    return this.http.get<Event[]>(this.url_node, httpOptions);
  }
```

Also created a model for the event to only get certain parameters:

**events.ts**

```
export class Event{

  CodEspec: number;
  NomeEspec: string;
  DiaHoraEspecs: Date[];

}
```

The in the event component where i want to show the JSON i call the function geteventos from the service.

**events.component.ts**

```
export class EventsComponent implements OnInit {

  events: Event[];

  constructor(private ticketlineservice: TicketlineService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.ticketlineservice.getEventos().subscribe(events => {
      this.events = events;
    });
  }
}
```

**events.component.html**

```
<div class="text-center">
    <ul *ngFor="let event of events">
        <li class="btn bg-primary text-center">
            <h2>Evento:</h2> 
            <p>{{ event.NomeEspec }}</p>
            <p>{{ event.CodEspec }}</p>
            <p>{{ event.DiaHoraEspecs }}</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Problem:** Create for every Event object a li element with the corresponding information. At the moment it only creates on li element and doesn't show the JSON information

Comment: You are getting repeated `uls` instead of `lis`, put your `*ngFor` over the `li`

Comment: what is the content of `events` which are returned in `subscribe`?

Comment: `subscribe` returns an array with two arrays inside and in those two is the information of every event

Comment: @LuisMaia but you showed the JSON response, and there is no array with arrays inside. You should be clear which response exactly you are getting.

Comment: @porgo returns the following: `0:
Events: Array(2)
0: {...}
1: {...}`

Comment: @LuisMaia check my answer, I edited this. Now it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this json which are you presenting `Events` is a property. So you should get this property from `events` in `subscribe`:

```
this.ticketlineservice.getEventos().subscribe(events => {
  this.events = events.Events;
});
```

**But** if you are getting array as response with `Events` property inside (as you mentioned it in comment), you should do this like this:

```
this.ticketlineservice.getEventos().subscribe(events => {
  this.events = events[0].Events;
});
```

And you should also in further steps change a type of return `getEventos():Observable<Event[]>` because as you showed this is not true (according to this sample JSON response). You are not returning `Event` array.

And also in HTML file you should make changes like @Dusan Radovanovic post as his answer. So it should like this:

```
<div class="text-center">
  <ul>
    <li class="btn bg-primary text-center" *ngFor="let event of events">
      <h2>Evento:</h2> 
      <p>{{ event.NomeEspec }}</p>
      <p>{{ event.CodEspec }}</p>
      <p>{{ event.DiaHoraEspecs }}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: In the model of event i need to change anything? Because I´m getting the following error `Type 'Event' is missing the following properties from type 'Event[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more`

Comment: `this.events = events[0];`, `this.events` returns the error in the comment above: `Type 'Event' is missing the following properties from type 'Event[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more`

Comment: you are getting this because you have a return type `Event[]` from observable in your service, change this for `any[]`: `getEventos():Observable<any[]>`

Comment: Returns an error in the HTML `Can´t iterate over an object ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'` i changed to `*ng-repeat="event in events"` but also returns an error `Can't bind to 'ng-repeat' since it isn't a known property of 'li'.`

Comment: I also checked once again the response you are getting, and I noticed my error (I think so). It should be: `this.events = events[0].Events;`.

Comment: Yes makes sense, i also changed back the service to `<Event[]>` and still works, thanks for the help

Comment: No problem, sorry for misunderstanding. Im glad that now everything is ok.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of iterating over `ul` elements you should iterate over `li` elements

```
 <div class="text-center">
        <ul>
            <li class="btn bg-primary text-center" *ngFor="let event of events">
                <h2>Evento:</h2> 
                <p>{{ event.NomeEspec }}</p>
                <p>{{ event.CodEspec }}</p>
                <p>{{ event.DiaHoraEspecs }}</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Still only creates a single li element and doesn't show the JSON information

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is not an array, it is an object.

Inside your subscribe, I think you probably want to do this:

```
  this.events = events.Events;
```

As others have mentioned, with your current code you should create two `ul` lists.  If you want to create a single list with two items you'll need something like this:

```
<ul >
    <li class="btn bg-primary text-center" *ngFor="let event of events">
        <h2>Evento:</h2> 
        <p>{{ event.NomeEspec }}</p>
        <p>{{ event.CodEspec }}</p>
        <p>{{ event.DiaHoraEspecs }}</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Moving the `*ngFor` from the `ul` to the `li`

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to your problem here.

From the response please pick the Events array and assign it to the events class level variable in **event.component.ts**

```
export class EventsComponent implements OnInit {

  events: Event[];

  constructor(private ticketlineservice: TicketlineService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.ticketlineservice.getEventos().subscribe(events => {
      this.events = events.Events;// This is the change for getting only events from the response
    });
  }
}
```

This way you will have only the events array rather than the entire response.

The second step is to as pointed out by main run a loop on the li rather than the ul as shown below:

```
<div class="text-center">
        <ul>
            <li class="btn bg-primary text-center" *ngFor="let event of events">
                <h2>Evento:</h2> 
                <p>{{ event.NomeEspec }}</p>
                <p>{{ event.CodEspec }}</p>
                <p>{{ event.DiaHoraEspecs }}</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

I would like to add one more good practice which is to add elvis operator or safe operator so that your HTML does not fail.

**event.NomeEspec** --->  **event?.NomeEspec**

This way if event is ***undefined*** then we are safely accessing the properties of the event object.

**Update**

```
getEventos():Observable<Event[]>{
    //get todos os eventos
    return this.http.get<Event[]>(this.url_node, httpOptions);
  }
```

here you are type casting the response to Event[] whcih you will have to change a bit as shown below.

```
**getEventos():Observable<Event[]>{
    //get todos os eventos
    return this.http.get<Event[]>(this.url_node, httpOptions).map(response=> response.Events);// map operstor takes your response and sends the Events array as a part of the response for your HTTP call.
  }**
```

Comment: I already alter the html, but when I change the `event.component.ts` to `this.events = events.Events;` it returns the following error `Property 'Events' does not exist on type 'Event[]'.`

Comment: Hi @LuisMaia I have updated the answer please check if that helps.You need to pick the Events array from response before typecasting the response which you are doing when you say `this.http.get<Event[]>`.So please see the updated asnwer and let me know if it helps.